# How does one identify the weakest preconditions in Hoare triples, when a variable has been sampled from a uniform distribution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am learning about Dijkstra's weakest precondition inference technique (I have a Undergraduate and Master's in Mechanical Engineering). I have understood the basics of this technique from [here](https://www.cs.williams.edu/%7Efreund/cs326/ReasoningPart1.html). I'd like to know what happens if the set of equations is stochastic in nature. Here is a minimal example that I came up with, on the fly. Could someone please tell me the preconditions for these equations -

```
{What's the precondition for x here}

x ~ Uniform(0,1)

{ x != -1 }

z = x + 1;

{ z != 0 }
```

Comment: What does "x ~ Uniform(0, 1)" mean?  If $x$ is not equal to $-1$, $x + 1$ is not equal to $0$ for any $x$ so the statement before the precondition on $x$ doesn't seem to be relevant.